# How to import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute to kotlin module?

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I'm writing annotation processor in Kotlin. It works, but I can not import `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute` class: Andtoid Strudio shows me it correctly, but during compilation I get `Unresolved reference: tools` at import line.

What I need to import?

Now this module imports only `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlinpoet`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add tools.jar from the JDK to the dependencies of your module:

```
compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
```

Comment: kotlin DSL: `implementation(files("${System.getProperty("java.home")}/../lib/tools.jar"))`